# error: type parameter `D` must be used as the type parameter for some local type

Tags: mongodb, rust, nickel

I'm using Nickel.rs with MongoDB to build a RESTful api.
I'd like to implement a generic `Responder` for the type `mongodb::error::Result<Option<bson::Document>>`.

This is the implementation I wrote based on the examples I found for `Responder`:

```
impl<D> Responder<D> for Result<Option<Document>> {

    fn respond<'a>(self, mut response: Response<'a, D>) -> MiddlewareResult<'a, D> {
        response.set(MediaType::Json);

        match self {
            Ok(Some(doc))=>{
                ApiResponse{data: Bson::Document(doc).to_json()}.to_json()
            },
            Ok(None)=>{
                response.set(StatusCode::NotFound);
                ApiError{error: "Not found".to_string()}.to_json()
            },
            Err(e)=>{
                response.set(StatusCode::InternalServerError);
                ApiError{error: format!("{}",e)}.to_json()
            }

        }
    }
}
```

and I'm getting the following error:

> error: type parameter `D` must be used as the type parameter for some
>   local type (e.g. `MyStruct<T>`); only traits defined in the current
>   crate can be implemented for a type parameter [E0210]

I ran `rustc --explain E0210` for an explanation and if my understanding is correct, I need to provide a trait `D` as a type argument to `impl<D>`, but I don't understand which trait to provide.

I tried `impl<D: =()>` but that produced the same error.

Comment: Where does the `Responder` trait come from?

Comment: "either the trait or the type you’re implementing it for must be defined [...]  in the same crate as the impl" https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/traits.html#rules-for-implementing-traits

Comment: The Responder trait comes from nickel: http://docs.nickel.rs/nickel/trait.Responder.html

Comment: @starblue: That's an answer. You might also expand it to explain tuple struct which can be used to wrap a type in a local one and thus implement traits with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you implement a trait then [either the trait or the type you are implementing it for must be defined in the same crate](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/traits.html#rules-for-implementing-traits).  In you example that is not the case: the trait `Responder` is defined by `nickel`, and `Result` is defined by `mongodb`.

The common way to work around this is to define your own type, by wrapping the desired type into a [tuple struct](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/structs.html#tuple-structs) with a single component (the so-called *newtype pattern*):

```
struct Result(mongodb::error::Result<Option<Document>>);

impl Responder for Result {
    ...
```

Comment: After reading your comment I understood what the explanation meant and I did pretty much exactly what you describe in your answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Based on starblue's answer, I replaced `ApiResponse` and `ApiError` with a tuple struct and refactored my code as follows:

```
struct ApiResponse<T>(T);

impl<D> Responder<D> for ApiResponse<Result<Option<Document>>> {

    fn respond<'a>(self, mut response: Response<'a, D>) -> MiddlewareResult<'a, D> {

        let mut d = BTreeMap::new();
        match self.0 {
            Ok(Some(doc))=>{
                d.insert("data".to_string(),Bson::Document(doc).to_json());
            },
            Ok(None)=>{
                response.set(StatusCode::NotFound);
                d.insert("error".to_string(),"Not Found".to_json());
            },
            Err(e)=>{
                response.set(StatusCode::InternalServerError);
                d.insert("error".to_string(),format!("{}",e).to_json());
            }

        }
        response.set(MediaType::Json);
        response.send(Json::Object(d))
    }
}
```